# IDX Real Estate Python Code Unix Server Setup

Tags: python, wordpress, unix

Im trying to set up my wordpress site to have an automatic real estate feed and I'm following [this](http://www.shift8web.com/blog/treb-idx-wordpress-integration/) walk through. I don't know what Im doing wrong.

I set up a remote server terminal control through an SSH key, and the server is unix.

When I use use the command `treb_wordpress.py install` it gives me this error

> line 22, in ?
>       import csv, sys, urllib, urlparse, string, time, locale, os, os.path, socket, re, requests, xmlrpclib,errno
>   ImportError: No module named requests

I downloaded python-wordpress-xmlrpc-master and put the files on the server but when I try to install it through the terminal (by entering `setup.py install`)
I get `: No such file or directory`

As you can tell Im totally lost. If someone could help me out with this it would be amazing!

Comment: try to use with ppm in-place of SSH

Comment: that did not help. Let me elaborate I can edit setup.py to change the chmod to +x. After I do that and then try to install setup.py I get "No such file or directory"

I tried setting the permissions to 777 but that did not make a difference.

Comment: If you're on unix, you probably need to do `./setup.py install`.  Or better still, use [pip](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)